# Wordpress theme customization file location

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new to Wordpress and I need to know, once I customize a theme using the Theme Customization page (Appearance -> Themes -> {Any theme} -> Customize) where is that modification saved? I went and manually searched for my modification (let's say I changed the Title from "My Title" to "AwesomeWordpress") in the `wp-content/themes/{My Theme}` and didn't find the new value. I did this by ssh-ing to my instance, going to the `wp-content/themes/{My Theme}` folder and running `rg "AwesomeWordpress"` and it didn't show anything.

This leads me to think that one of two things might be happening: either WP is saving my modifications into another folder (which I might spend a long time of trial and error searching just to find that, in fact, it doesn't save it to a folder) or it gets saved to the database (finding out is exactly the same problem for me that the one before, just in this case using SQL queries....), or there's a third option that I haven't considered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Changes such as that would be stored within the database tables.

Please read over this to better understand the file system and database: https://www.optimizesmart.com/wordpress-ninja-15-minutes/